# Uno Material bottomNavigationBar

Tags: material-ui, uno-platform

I am implementing the bottomNavigationBar on the Uno Platform for my app.  I have everything else working- but am having trouble changing either the color or the opacity of the ripple effect when an icon is pressed.  I either need to change the opacity or the color of the effect.  What is the name of the property I need to modify- and is it a color or percentage?  Thanks for your help!

Here is a sample of the styles I have tried:

```
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected" Color="Green"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Green"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed" Color="Green"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed" Color="Green"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground"  Color="Blue" />
        <Color x:Key="MaterialPrimaryColor">Green</Color>
        <Color x:Key="MaterialSecondaryColor">LightGreen</Color>
        <Color x:Key="MaterialBottomNavForegroundColor">Green</Color>
        <Color x:Key="MaterialBottomNavUncheckedForegroundBrush">Blue</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialBottomNavBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF2F2F2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The resource to change the ripple effect color is `MaterialBottomNavPressedBrush`

Here's how you can find out which resources apply where:

1. Look up the style on github
2. Find in the XAML template where the resource is used
3. Note the name
4. Override it in your application's XAML

Here's where it is for this example [github link](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Material/blob/aaf0e803b847f47cf7466f39096c90b9e4353a6d/src/library/Uno.Material/Styles/Controls/BottomNavigationBarItem.xaml#L141)

Comment: I tried what you said- and think I may still be missing something.  Here is my code: `code`
            
            <Color x:Key="MaterialBottomNavUncheckedForegroundBrush">DarkOrange</Color>
             <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialBottomNavBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF2F2F2"/>
            <Color x:key="MaterialOnSurfaceColor">DarkGreen</Color>
            <SolidColorBrush x:key="MaterialBottomNavPressedBrush" Color="{StaticResource MaterialOnSurfaceColor}" Opacity="0.20"/> `code`

Answer (score 0):

So- I figured out the issue- I needed both MaterialBottomNavPressedBrush and MaterialBottomNavUncheckedForegroundBrush. Because of my color choices- if I left one out- it defaulted to white and you could not see it.  Thanks to matfillion for pointing me in the right direction.  Here is my example code:

```
<Color x:Key="MaterialPrimaryColor">Blue</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialColor">Yellow</SolidColorBrush> 
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialBottomNavPressedBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MaterialColor}" Opacity="0.10" /> 
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialBottomNavUncheckedForegroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MaterialPrimaryColor}" Opacity=".50" />
```